# Constant in EF causes exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception, enums

I have the following code. but it causes exception.

```
                using (var context = new blogEntities())
                {
                    var listOfComments = context.Comments
                        .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateDate)
                        .Where(c => c.CreateDate > fromDate)
                        .Select(c => new NewsFeedData()
                        {
                            ArticleID = c.ArticleID,
                            CommentID = c.CommentID,
                            Text = c.CommentText,
                            Author = c.Author,
                            CreateDate = c.CreateDate,
                            Type = 'C'
                        }).ToList();
                 }
```

Than I tried enum but there is some problems. What is the best way to achieve what I want?
I want to assign some constant to Type

Comment: What is the exception? Is "Type" a character?

Comment: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

NotSupportedException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple approach is to fetch all the values from the database into an anonymous type, then use `AsEnumerable` to switch into LINQ to Objects before the final projection:

```
using (var context = new blogEntities())
{
    var listOfComments = context.Comments
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateDate)
        .Where(c => c.CreateDate > fromDate)
        .Select(c => new { c.ArticleID, c.CommentID, c.CommentText,
                           c.Author, c.CreateDate })
        .AsEnumerable() // Switch into LINQ to Objects
        .Select(c => new NewsFeedData
        {
            ArticleID = c.ArticleID,
            CommentID = c.CommentID,
            Text = c.CommentText,
            Author = c.Author,
            CreateDate = c.CreateDate,
            Type = 'C'
        }).ToList();
 }
```

Comment: @levanlevi: This solution is perfect! Very cool trick... I doubt there is a way with less code.

Comment: @levanlevi: What do you mean by "too large"? I've only added three lines of code... if it solves your problem, is three lines really too much to ask?

Comment: OK, less code :) Use `new NewsFeedData` before the `AsEnumerable` and after it: `.Select(c => { c.Type = 'C'; return c; }).ToList()`.

Comment: @Slauma: Ick - while that should work, I'd definitely go with my version instead ;)